# Mean of 4 numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the mean of 4 different integers is 75 and the largest of them is 90, what could be the least possible value of the smallest integer?

Comment: 33, 88, 89, 90.

Answer (score 2):

To find smallest integer you need to maximise the other three, which means the numbers are $90,89,88,x$, where $x$ is the smallest. Since the average is 75, this means $\frac{90+89+88+x}{4}=75$. Solve this equation for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a+b+c+d}4=75\iff a+b+c+d=300$$ where $a<b<c<d$

If $d=90, a+b+c=300-90=210\iff a=210-(b+c)$

$c\le d-1=89, b\le c-1\le d-2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: To make the smallest of the 4 numbers as small as possible, while still keeping the average at 75, the other numbers must be as large as possible.  How big are the other 3 numbers?